# musl-gcc: undefined reference to __memcpy_chk

Tags: c, gcc, musl

I need to compile a C program against musl-libc to make it run on an embedded device. However, I'm failing to compile the program. The source depends on a couple libraries which I pass to the linker like so:

`/usr/local/musl/bin/musl-gcc app.c -o app -I../lib -lzlog -lfilter`

This is the output I get:

```
/usr/local/musl/lib/libzlog.a(category.o): In function `strcpy':
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:110: undefined reference to `__memcpy_chk'
/usr/local/musl/lib/libzlog.a(conf.o): In function `strcpy':
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:110: undefined reference to `__strcpy_chk'
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:110: undefined reference to `__strcpy_chk'
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:110: undefined reference to `__strcpy_chk'
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:110: undefined reference to `__strcpy_chk'
/usr/local/musl/lib/libzlog.a(event.o): In function `sprintf':
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:33: undefined reference to `__sprintf_chk'
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:33: undefined reference to `__sprintf_chk'
/usr/local/musl/lib/libzlog.a(format.o): In function `memcpy':
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:53: undefined reference to `__memcpy_chk'
/usr/local/musl/lib/libzlog.a(record.o): In function `strcpy':
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:110: undefined reference to `__memcpy_chk'
/usr/local/musl/lib/libzlog.a(rotater.o): In function `snprintf':
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:64: undefined reference to `__snprintf_chk'
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:64: undefined reference to `__snprintf_chk'
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:64: undefined reference to `__snprintf_chk'
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:64: undefined reference to `__snprintf_chk'
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:64: undefined reference to `__snprintf_chk'
/usr/local/musl/lib/libzlog.a(rule.o): In function `syslog':
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/syslog.h:31: undefined reference to `__syslog_chk'
/usr/local/musl/lib/libzlog.a(rule.o): In function `strcpy':
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:110: undefined reference to `__strcpy_chk'
/usr/local/musl/lib/libzlog.a(rule.o): In function `memcpy':
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:53: undefined reference to `__memcpy_chk'
/usr/local/musl/lib/libzlog.a(spec.o): In function `sprintf':
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:33: undefined reference to `__sprintf_chk'
/usr/local/musl/lib/libzlog.a(zc_profile.o): In function `vfprintf':
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:127: undefined reference to `__vfprintf_chk'
/usr/local/musl/lib/libzlog.a(zc_profile.o): In function `fprintf':
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:97: undefined reference to `__fprintf_chk'
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:97: undefined reference to `__fprintf_chk'
/usr/local/musl/lib/libzlog.a(zc_util.o): In function `snprintf':
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:64: undefined reference to `__snprintf_chk'
/usr/local/musl/lib/libzlog.a(buf.o): In function `strcpy':
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:110: undefined reference to `__memcpy_chk'
/usr/local/musl/lib/libzlog.a(buf.o): In function `vsnprintf':
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:77: undefined reference to `__vsnprintf_chk'
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:77: undefined reference to `__vsnprintf_chk'
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:77: undefined reference to `__vsnprintf_chk'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The same command with gcc works fine.
Are these functions not implemented in musl?

Comment: regarding: `-I../lib`  This is telling the compiler where the header files are located, NOT where the libraries are located.  To tell the linker where the libraries are located use `-L../lib`   Notice the capital 'L' rather than the capital 'I'`

Comment: You're right of course. The setup was kind of weird. The header files were not needed for the library in question. That library was in the standard lookup path of the linker.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The include paths in your question are all glibc files, so it looks like the library you're trying to link to was built with glibc. This can sometimes be made to work, but there are limitations. In your case, it was built with the glibc version of `_FORTIFY_SOURCE`, which uses symbols from glibc that are not presently available in musl (the `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` implementation typically used on musl works differently). Making this work has been on the long-term agenda for a long time, but not a priority; if you can, it's much better to rebuild the library against musl.

Comment: @Antti you mean from the author of musl himself?

Comment: Of course, that was it. I could get my hands on the source and compiled it against musl. Works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is irrelevant to your case but I had same `__memcpy_chk` issue when cross-compiling using MinGW under linux.

And this undefined reference was fixed by adding `-lssp` flag to linker. If you have `configure` then you can do `LDFLAGS="-lssp" ./configure ...`